# Removing objects from a list and iterator problems

Tags: java, android, google-maps, arraylist, iterator

Im having problems with removing items from an arraylist using an iterator. My aim is to retrieve points within a certain radius and cluster them into a set of groups. I am using the initial points as a reference. The code has an initial for loop that will run through each place, then for each place an inner for loop is created to check the radius between the reference place and the rest of places. If the radius between both reference place and other place is less than a threshold i set, it will be added to the arraylist grouped with other similar points. As they are added to groups they will be removed from the original arraylist.

However i am getting problems such as it either only performs the outer for loop once or i get an `IllegalStateException`.

Here is the code:

```
HashMap<Place, ArrayList<Place>> sets = new HashMap<Place, ArrayList<Place>>();

private void cluster(ArrayList<Place> places) {

    for (Iterator<Place> iterator = places.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Place pl = iterator.next();
        ArrayList<Place> subset = new ArrayList<Place>(); // Group
        GeoPoint g = new GeoPoint((int) (pl.getGeometry().getLocation()
                .getLat() * 1e6), (int) (pl.getGeometry().getLocation()
                .getLng() * 1e6));
        Point point = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(g, point);
        sets.put(pl, subset);
        subset.add(pl);
        iterator.remove();

        for (Iterator<Place> iterator2 = places.iterator(); iterator2
                .hasNext();) {
            Place pl2 = iterator2.next();
            int threshold = 100;
            GeoPoint g2 = new GeoPoint((int) (pl2.getGeometry()
                    .getLocation().getLat() * 1e6), (int) (pl2
                    .getGeometry().getLocation().getLng() * 1e6));
            Point point2 = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(g2, point);
            int dx = Math.abs(point2.x - point.x);  
            int dy = Math.abs(point2.y - point.y);
            if (dx < threshold && dy < threshold) {
                subset.add(pl2);
                iterator2.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for the info overload, would really appreciate the help.

Thanks in advance peeps

Rehan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are stepping the outer iterator inside the inner loop. It looks like these lines might be in error:

```
for (Iterator<Place> iterator2 = places.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Place pl2 = iterator.next();
```

Looks like maybe you copied and pasted without changing the terminating condition in the loop and the following line:

```
for (Iterator<Place> iterator2 = places.iterator(); iterator2.hasNext();) {
       Place pl2 = iterator2.next();
```

Comment: yeah sorry about that, i just noticed it, i just edited it too. Yeah i fixed the illegalstateException thanks. But now im getting a ConcurrentModification Exception. :S the thing is i want both for loops to iterate over the same list, and the inner for loop might edit the place list too as in delete places, is this not allowed?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish by removing points from the same list in two places? It seems like you will hit some problems if you remove items from the inner loop while the outer loop is iterating. Also, what is the reason for the call to `iterator.remove()` prior to starting the inner loop?

Comment: my aim is group places together based on there radius, so the outer loop will be the key of the hashmap (the reference point) and the inner loop adds the list of places that are in its radius, hence why its being added to a list. I called iterator.remove() so that when it performs the innerloop it doesnt find the reference point being used

Comment: im removing places during the inner loop because if it finds a place that its within the reference place point radius it will not be used later as a reference point because it has already been grouped in the hashmap as a value. Keys in the hashmap are points that are not in the radius of other reference points and are not grouped yet.

Answer (score 2):

running multiple iterators over the same list isnt allowed. So you will get a concurrentmodification exception.  Better make a copy of the array list, in the inner loop update the data in the position of copy where you want to update. In short,change your logic

Answer (score 1):

I guess you gets exception because you change list while iterating it.

At first, I would use `for (... in ...)` construction.

Second, I think you have to copy `places` an iterating it, but deleting from `places`.